# new File("full_path_file_name).lastModified()) returns 0 on IOS 14.4.2

Tags: codenameone

I display the Last Modified Date of a File on storage.

I use new Date(new File("full_path_file_name).lastModified()))
On IOS Only, it returns "Wed Dec 31, 1969 07:00PM" (Close to Unix epoch Time)

Android and PC behave correctly.

Thoughts?

Turns out that on IOS, Files stored in the FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath() are not exposed to my app.
Listing files in the home directory is always empty on IOS.
I have a browser component that lists all files starting at homepath:
Node[] NodesOnPath = node.nodeParent.getNodesOnPath();
Only Directories in homepath are enumerated.

I am however able to get file dates and length etc on all files not in homepath.

I use Storage class to Read & Write Externalizable Objects (Vector). Is very useful for us.
Q. Is it possible to force the Storage Class to read/write in a sub directory of homepath?
The thinking is file system properties will be then available to my app.

Comment: What's the output of `length()` or `exists()`? How did you get/create the file?

Comment: Files are Saved Using: Storage.getInstance().writeObject(filePath, data); where filepath is absolute.

Answer (score 0):

`Storage` != `FileSystemStorage`. An object in `Storage` isn't always reachable in the file API. You should use the storage API to access the size of this object.

Comment: Turns out that on IOS, Files stored in the FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath() are not exposed to my app. Listing files in the home directory is always empty on IOS. I have a browser component that lists all files starting at homepath: Node[] NodesOnPath = node.nodeParent.getNodesOnPath(); Only Directories in homepath are enumerated.

I am however, able to get file properties on all files not in homepath.

Comment: THose are not the same things, Every app has its own isolated home path